# Convert DOC to DOCX with Python without intermediate written output file to disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, command-line, command-prompt

**Problem:**

> to convert `input_file.doc` to `output_file.docx` with **Python script**

I need to do that with python script and therefore I have to use only software that understands commands.
As my research has shown, the only way is to use `Word` itself (manually of even automated), or special MS utility called `wordconv.exe`, which can handle this task via cmd and is bundled with any MS office since 2007.

*Any other software doesn't work for me because **my files contains rarely used text formatting.***

So, the only way to go is `wordconv.exe`, that can run with command like this:

> `wordconv.exe -oice -nme <input file> <output file>`

Stumbling block to me is that `wordconv.exe` output is written file to HDD. So, I need to handle all the process:

1. Convert file
2. Read it from disk
3. Delete file after reading

All that makes my work much slower because of many unnecessary operations.

I would like to find out how to catch `output_file.docx` as `STDOUT` or in another way (maybe like output in console)?

Comment: What intermediate file ? There is input file and output file. The output file has a different filename by design (different file extension) so there is _no way_ you can avoid having two files or avoid having to delete one file. You start with `input_file.doc` and end with `output_file.docx`.

Comment: @reportgunner I'm hoping there is some way. I tried to redirect `output_file.docx` to CON using command `wordconv.exe -oice -nme input_file.doc con:`. The `output_file.docx` is not created in this case, but nothing is in console and nothing can be captured with `subprocess.PIPE` in `STDOUT`. Maybe there is another way, or there is possibility to catch that `CON:` redirection, or there are some command line arguments that could help me?..

Comment: what are you trying to do with the `.docx` file after it is converted ?

Comment: @reportgunner after conversion they're converting further to special formatted HTMLs documents

Comment: A possible improvement would be to create a memory mapped drive and write to that. I doubt you can catch the output as STDOUT.